# prove that there exists $q\in \Bbb Q$ such that $x<cq<y$.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, real-numbers

> For any $c\in \Bbb R$ with $c>0$ and $x<y$, prove that there exists $q\in \Bbb Q$ such that $x<cq<y$.

Since $c>0$, so by Archimedean property, there exists a natural number $n$ such that $cn>x$, which proves the 1st part of the inequality. How to prove the 2nd part of the inequality ? Any hint. please ?!

**Edit:** Again since $\frac 1c>0$ so by Archimedean property, $\frac 1c. m>\frac 1y$ which implies $y>\frac cm$. How to combine these two inequalities to get the desired result ?

Comment: If you have any questions on the answer I gave, feel free to ask. I enjoy helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Density of $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

*For every two real numbers $a$ and $b$ with $a < b$, there exists a rational number $r$ satisfying $a < r < b$.*

(I got this from *Understanding Analysis 2nd ed.* by S., Abbott see https://1lib.us/book/2551362/75e2a5)

#### Answer

Note: I didn't think enough about what you wanted to prove.

We want to show there for any choice of $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $a<b$, we have $a < c \frac{m}{n} < b$, where $c > 0$ and $n \neq 0$. Note that the inequality $a < c \frac{m}{n} < b$ is equivalent to $na < cm < nb$. For the inequality $na < cm$ in $na < cm < nb$, we can choose $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $c(m - 1) \leq na < cm$. The inequality $na < cm$ here is equivalent to $a < \frac{cm}{n}$. Now using Archimedes Principle, we know that there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{c}{n} < b- a$, which is equivalent to $a < b - \frac{c}{n}$. So we have from the $c(m - 1) \leq na$ in $c(m - 1) \leq na < cm$ that
\begin{align}
c(m - 1) &\leq na\\
cm &\leq na + c\\
&< n(b - \frac{c}{n}) + c\\
&= nb - c + c
\end{align}
So $cm < nb$ means that $\frac{cm}{n}<b$. Together with the earlier inequality $a < \frac{cm}{n}$, we have $a <  \frac{cm}{n} < b$, as desired.

#### Prev. Answer

For any $\frac{a}{c}, \frac{b}{c} \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\frac{a}{c} < \frac{b}{c}$ where $c > 0$, we have $ \frac{a}{c} < r < \frac{b}{c}$ for some $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ by the Density of the Rationals. After multiplying each term in the inequality by $c$, we get that $a < cr < b$, as desired.

Hope this helps.